# React-Redux app: How to make that in this field on my page only some part of data displayed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have some API. And I take the data from this API and display it on the page as a list table. But in field **Time** I want only some part of information is displayed on my page.

Now data displayed like this:

[image]

But I need it to be like this (only hours and minutes):

[image]
How to implement it in my case? Just please without links, I need help specifically in my situation.

Here is a component that displays a table list(TableData.js):
import React from "react";

```
export default ({ data }) => (
    <div className="tableContainer">
  <table className="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Terminal</th>
        <th>Gate</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>Airline</th>
        <th>Flight</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map(item => (
        <tr key={item.ID}>
          <td>{item.term}</td>
          <td>{item.gateNo}</td>
          <td>{item.actual}</td>
          <td>
            {item["airportToID.city_en"]
              ? item["airportToID.city_en"]
              : item["airportFromID.city_en"]}
          </td>
        <td>{item.airline.en.name}</td>
          <td>{item["planeTypeID.code"]}</td>
          <td>{item.status}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
);
```

airplanes.js(reducer):

```
import { searchFilter } from "../components/app";

export function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_SHIFT":
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        shift: action.shift
      });
    case "SET_SEARCH":
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        search: action.search.toLowerCase()
      });
    case "RUN_FILTER":
      var newData = state.data[action.shift || state.shift].filter(x => {
        return (
          x["planeTypeID.code"].toLowerCase().includes(action.search || state.search)
        );
      });
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        shift: action.shift || state.shift,
        search: action.search || state.search,
        filteredData: searchFilter(state.search, newData)
      });
    case "LOAD_DATA_START":
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        day: action.day
      });
    case "LOAD_DATA_END":
      var newData = action.payload.data[state.shift].filter(x => {
        return (
          x["planeTypeID.code"] &&
          x["planeTypeID.code"].toLowerCase().includes(action.search || state.search)
        );
      });
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        data: action.payload.data,
        shift: Object.keys(action.payload.data)[0],
        filteredData: searchFilter(state.search, newData)
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

app.js(main component):

```
export function searchFilter(search, data) {
  return data.filter(n => n["planeTypeID.code"].toLowerCase().includes(search));
}

const days = ["23-08-2019", "24-08-2019", "25-08-2019"];

class Root extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchData(days[this.props.propReducer.day]);
  }

  render() {
    const { onFilter, onSetSearch, onFetchData } = this.props;
    const { search, shift, data, filteredData } = this.props.propReducer;

    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>

        <h1>SEARCH FLIGHT</h1>

        <TableSearch value={search} onChange={e => onSetSearch(e.target.value)} 
         onSearch={value => onFilter({ search: value })}onSearch={() => onFilter()}/>

        <div className="buttonShift">
          {data && Object.keys(data).map(n => (
            <button data-shift={n} onClick={e => onFilter({ shift: e.target.dataset.shift })} className={n === shift ? "active" : "noActive"}>{n}</button>
          ))}
        </div>

        <div className="buttonDays">
          {days && days.map((day, i) => (
            <button className="buttonDaysOne" key={day} onClick={() => onFetchData(day)}>{day}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>

        {data && <TableData data={filteredData} />}

        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export const ConnectedRoot = connect(
  state => state,
  dispatch => ({
    onFilter: args => dispatch({ type: "RUN_FILTER", ...args }),
    onSetSearch: search => dispatch({ type: "SET_SEARCH", search }),
    onFetchData: day => dispatch(fetchData(day))
  })
)(Root);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a matter of formatting the date value before rendering, you don't want to change any of your reducer code e.g.

```
const hours = `${dt.getHours()}:${dt.getMinutes()}`;
```

This will render the time locally dependant on the browsers Timezone i.e.

```
const dt = new Date('2019-11-11T11:43:18.026Z');
console.log(`${dt.getHours()}:${dt.getMinutes()}`); // 22:43 if in Australia (UTC+11)
```

Here's the change in `TableData.js` you need to make:

```
{data.map(item => {
  const dt = new Date(item.actual);
  const mins = dt.getMinutes();
  return (
    <tr key={item.ID}>
      <td>{item.term}</td>
      <td>{item.gateNo}</td>
      <td>{`${dt.getHours()}:${mins < 10 ? '0' : ''}${mins}`}</td>
      <td>
        {item["airportToID.city_en"]
          ? item["airportToID.city_en"]
          : item["airportFromID.city_en"]}
      </td>
    <td>{item.airline.en.name}</td>
      <td>{item["planeTypeID.code"]}</td>
      <td>{item.status}</td>
    </tr>
  )
})}
```

Comment: thank you very much! can you help me integrate this into my code? I'm just new to programming...
all project code in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-olbgn

Comment: @TomasGidnop see [update](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-wlm7n), check changes to `TableData.js`.

Comment: Thank you again! you changed only file TableData.js?in other files did you not make changes?

Comment: @TomasGidnop no, you only need to change `TableData.js`. Also, see updated example as you need to handle scenarios where minutes are < 10

Comment: and what it means ```minutes are < 10```? that is, what is it for?

Comment: by the way, some time is not very good now, I marked red
http://i.piccy.info/i9/a1979f2d7c62083299cd2956390641b7/1573477625/10753/1334636/Screenshot_28.jpg

Comment: @TomasGidnop that's exactly what my code addresses, I didn't update the codesandbox so please refer to the code in my answer

Comment: can you take a look at my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806769/what-do-i-need-to-change-in-my-file-so-that-only-the-active-button-is-highlighte

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:-

```
const date = new Date(<date coming from API response>); // new Date("2019-08-22T23:50:00Z")
const hours = date.getHours();
const minutes = date.getMinutes();
```

Then you can display them in your component.

Comment: thank you very much! can you help me integrate this into my code? I'm just new to programming...
all project code in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-olbgn

Comment: @TomasGidnop I have updated your sandbox link. Please check if you can see the changes.

Comment: no, i don't see the change.try it like this:
1) in the right corner in sandbox, press the "fork" button, it copies my project but with a new address.
2) make changes
3) write me the address of the copied sandbox

Comment: Oops, here is the forked link - https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-9q3kq

Comment: Thank you again! you changed only file TableData.js?in other files did you not make changes?

Comment: @TomasGidnop Nope, I only changed TableData.js

Comment: As per my answer, this isn't enough. You also need to handle minutes < 10 minutes otherwise you get times like `4:5` rather than `4:05`

Comment: @Shivratna Kumar you can tell how to do it? I'm talking about: "minutes < 10 minutes"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object then use methods on the Date object like so:

```
let theDate = new Date("2019-08-22T23:50:00Z");
console.log(theDate.getHours() + ':' + theDate.getMinutes());
```

Would output:

```
0:50
```

Comment: Only if you are on `UTC+1` :)

Comment: @James Ah yes of course, apologies for missing that in my original answer :)